# IDEAJ - Git history master

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am a beginner and I use IntelliJ and no idea how to place my master to the same row with the HEAD. Master is behind HEAD. Please, find attached.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your local branch seems to be two commits ahead of the remote master branch.

All you have to do is push your commits via the green arrow at the top right of your Ide (or via the terminal : git push).

Comment: Hi thank you for your prompt answer. I work local.